# Remainder when $2005^{2002} + 2002^{2005}$ is divided by $2003$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the remainder when $2005^{2002} + 2002^{2005}$ is divided by $2003$ ?

Is there any better approach to this rather than using binomial theorem?

Comment: More generally for primes $p>2,$   $$(p+2)^{p-1}+(p-1)^{p+2}\equiv2^{p-1}+(-1)^{p+2}\pmod p\equiv1+(-1)$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

\begin{align*}
2005^{2002} + 2002^{2005} & \equiv (2)^{2002}+(-1)^{2005} \pmod{2003}\\
& \equiv 1-1
 \pmod{2003}\\
& \equiv 0 \pmod{2003}.
\end{align*}
The second last step follows from Fermat's little theorem (since $2003$ is prime), we have 
$$2^{2002} \equiv 1 \pmod{2003}.$$